# Изменение размеров модального окна мышкой

Tags: html, css, angular

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие сво-ва в css или html нужны, что бы можно было мышкой изменить размер модального окна. Используется фреймворк ангуляр

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Единственный элемент который можно растягивать это textarea, если хочешь растянуть его на весь блок то так и скажи

Comment: @Андрей Тут Вам нужен не `css`, а `js`. Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый код данного модального окна.